# How do you properly return a value from a method? Receiving an odd error on invalid input

Tags: java, function, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double score = 0, avg, sum = 0;
    int index = 0, count = 0, num = 0;

    num = readInput(keyboard, num);

    double Test[] = new double[num];
    System.out.print("\n");

    while(count < Test.length)
    {
      System.out.printf("Enter your test score #%d:", count + 1);
      try
      {
        score = keyboard.nextDouble();
      }

      catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e)
      {
        System.out.print("You have entered a non-numerical value, please try again\n");
        keyboard.next();
        continue;
      }
      if (score >= 0)
      {
        Test[count] = score;
        sum = sum + score;
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.print("You have entered an invalid grade, please try again\n");
        continue;
      }
      count++;
    }

    double maxValue = Test[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < Test.length; i++) 
    {
      if (Test[i] > maxValue) 
      {
        maxValue = Test[i];
      }
    }  

    double minValue = Test[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < Test.length; i++) 
    {
      if (Test[i] < minValue) 
      {
        minValue = Test[i];
        index = i;
      }
    }

    System.out.print("\nThe highest value is: " + maxValue + "\n");
    System.out.print("The lowest value is: " + minValue + "\n");

    avg = sum / Test.length;
    System.out.printf("Your grade average is: %.1f \n\n", avg);

    System.out.print("Would you like to drop the lowest grade: Y or N:");
    char choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
    {
      double newSum = sum - minValue;
      double newAvg = newSum / (Test.length - 1);

      System.out.print("\nYour old scores were: ");
      System.out.print(Test[0]);
      for (int i = 1; i < Test.length; i++) 
      { 
        System.out.print(", " + Test[i]);
      }

      System.out.print("\n\nYour new scores are: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < Test.length; i++) 
      { 
        if (index != 0 && i != index)
        {
          if (i >= 1)
          {
            System.out.print(", "); 
          }  
          System.out.print(Test[i]);
        } 
        else if (i != index)
        {
          if (i >= 2)
          {
            System.out.print(", "); 
          }  
          System.out.print(Test[i]); 
        }
      }

      System.out.printf("\n\nYour new average is: %.1f\n", newAvg);
    }
    else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n')
    {
      System.out.print("Your average has stayed the same.\n");
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.print("You have entered an invalid response. Bye.\n");
      return;
    }

  }

  public static int readInput(Scanner keyboard, int val)
  {
    System.out.print("\nHow many scores would you like to enter:");
    val = 0;
    try
    {
      val = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e)
    {
      System.out.print("You have entered a non-numerical value.\n");
      keyboard.next();
      readInput(keyboard, val);
    }

    if (val < 0)
    {
      System.out.print("You have entered a negative value.\n");
      readInput(keyboard, val);
    }
    else if (val == 0)
    {
      System.out.print("If you have no test grades then you do not need this program.\n");
      readInput(keyboard, val);
    }
    return val;
  }
}
```

The error is due to the function at the bottom of the code.

This is my output currently:

How many scores would you like to enter: h
You have entered a non-numerical value.

How many scores would you like to enter: 8
If you have no test grades then you do not need this program.

How many scores would you like to enter: 8

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Main.main(Main.java:53)
exited with non-zero status

It seems to not recognize the second value entered. The program thinks its zero even though I entered 8 and I cant figure out why. And on the third entry after an invalid entry the program crashes. Note: if the user inputs a valid value on the first try the program works fine. It's only when the user inputs invalid input first that this error happens.

EDIT: I understand that the error is because my array has no values in it but I am asking why this is happening. The value is not returning from the function after invalid input is entered so the array is trying to run while empty.

Comment: The problem is on the `readInput(keyboard, val);` lines in your `catch` blocks: you're not doing anything with the return value. You want something like `val = readInput(keyboard, val);`; otherwise, you'll just return zero.

Comment: Note that you don't need to pass in `val` to the `readInput` method, as you don't use the value. Just declare a local variable.